# Generate new geometric network from intersection between curent network and polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geometric-network, taudem

I have generated a stream network using the "Strea Reach and Watershed" tool from the [TauDEM](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/index.html) toolbox.

Within the stream reach dataset there are fields that give an ID to the stream segment and fields which state the upstream and downstream segments, i.e. a network.

I have a polygon shapefile with field boundaries. What I would like to do is create a point wherever the stream network crosses a field boundary and then join the points together with straight lines to represent links between the fields based on the stream network. I have managed to create points where intersections between the network and the field boundaries are, I am just unsure how to join these together with lines that follows the network.

I have illustrated what I mean below with crudely drawn red lines. Figure 1 is the basic form of what I would like to achieve i.e. connections between the field boundary intersections along the network.

Ideally I would like to achieve what is in figure 2 which is lines that follow the network stemming from the centroids of each field polygon, i.e. one line can represent all flow lines crossing into an adjacent field.

[image: Figure 1 - Field links based on intersections with field boundaries]

Figure 1 - Field links based on intersections with field boundaries

[image]

Figure 2 - Field links from centroid of polygon

As I stated I've used the TauDEM tool box in ArcGIS 10 so far, but am open to any other tools in ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Wow...  This is a tough one.  What you are trying to do seems like it would take a bit of human intuition which might be hard to replicate in ArcMap or QGIS.  Maybe through some sort of script that takes the x,y coordinates of vertices and their berrings in relation to the "field centroids" but that gets very messy and complicated.  Hopefully someone comes up with something for you. In the mean time, you might want to start an edit session :)